# Jenkins Pipeline cannot execute SH command file in a Windows slave

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm executing this code:

```
node('my_windows_slave') {
   sh 'ls'
}
```

In my Windows slave I can properly execute `sh` command:

[image]

But the pipeline script can't run the `.sh` file:

```
[Pipeline] sh
[D:\workspace\sandbox_pipeline] Running shell script
sh: D:\workspace\sandbox_pipeline@tmp\durable-2d7dd2f8\script.sh: command not found
```

What I could notice is that this `.sh` file is not even created, once I tried with `bat` and worked fined.

Any clue what could be the problem?

[UPDATE]

Jenkins somehow can't create the `SH` temporary file. Already checked the log, permissions, everything that came to my mind.

Comment: Set Env Varibale and do sysmlink to nohup.exe as suggested below
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45151156/3648023 After this setup you can use sh directly on your jenkinsfile

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will leave my workaround as an answer for while before approve it once I'm still not 100% sure about the root cause and might someone else show up with a elegant solution...

```
def shell(command) {
    return bat(returnStdout: true, script: "sh -x -c \"${command}\"").trim()
}
```

---

**Attention**

You still executing `SH` commands in a `CMD`, it means some `%d` for example can break your `SH` command.

Comment: Hi Marcelo. Thanks for the workaround. Just a small clarification: then instead of using e.g. "sh "gulp test"" in a script you'll be using "shell("gulp test")", right?

Comment: @Dedyshka yes!!

Comment: Great! That seems working but might require quotes around ${command}. Thanks.

Comment: So you ended up using `bat` instead of `sh`, as described in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45277544/3495031

Answer (score 7):

### Use the **`bat`** step instead of `sh`.

From Jenkins [docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/#windows):

> Windows-based systems should use the bat step for executing batch commands.

Comment: why once I want to use the shell DLL instead of the BAT from win?!

Comment: It's about good practices. `sh` is not a native Windows command, and the official docs recommends using `bat`.

Comment: its nonsense, sry, if you have something that is easy done my SHELL why not use it? why do not use something that is cross platform? There is nothing to do with best practices but what you like or not...

Comment: Spent hours trying to get shell to work, until I found this. Thanks, take my money. ;)