# Jenkins pipeline sh fail with "cannot run program nohup" on windows

Tags: bash, jenkins, windows-10, jenkins-pipeline

I have windows 10 and I want to execute the sh command in the Jenkinsfile from Jenkins pipeline using bash for Ubuntu for windows, but it doesn't work

I have the following stage in my Jenkins pipeline :

```
stage('sh how to') {
        steps {
            sh 'ls -l'
        }
    }
```

The error message is :

> [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\pipelineascode] Running shell script
>   Cannot run program "nohup" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\pipelineascode"): CreateProcess error=2, Le fichier spécifié est introuvable

I tried changing Jenkins parameter->shell executable with

> C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe

but same error...

how to run sh script using windows 10's bash?

Comment: You may be missing quotes around your path (containing spaces). If not double check the presence of the binary in the folder...  

Also, how is your stage code relevant to the given error ?

Comment: It didn't work with/without quotes... I tried with a shell script and a Basic command (ls -l) ... And that's this step who broke and send this error message !

Comment: My workaround might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41610192/575643

Answer (score 90, accepted):

From a very quick search, it looks like your error is related to the following issue : [JENKINS-33708](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33708)

The main cause looks like the `sh` step is not supported on the Windows. You may use `bat` or install `Cygwin` for instance.

Nevertheless two solutions were proposed in the previous link, suggesting you to do the following steps :

- Install [git-bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads)
- Ensure the Git\bin folder (i.e.: `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`) is in the global search path, in order for Jenkins to find sh.exe
- Make nohup available for Jenkins, doing the following in git-bash (adapt your paths accordingly) :

  - mklink "C:\Program Files\Git\**bin**\nohup.exe" "C:\Program Files\git\usr\bin\nohup.exe"
  - mklink "C:\Program Files\Git\**bin**\msys-2.0.dll" "C:\Program Files\git\usr\bin\msys-2.0.dll"
  - mklink "C:\Program Files\Git\**bin**\msys-iconv-2.dll" "C:\Program Files\git\usr\bin\msys-iconv-2.dll"
  - mklink "C:\Program Files\Git\**bin**\msys-intl-8.dll" "C:\Program Files\git\usr\bin\msys-intl-8.dll"

Depending on your installation you may have to use these paths :

- mklink "C:\Program Files\Git\**cmd**\nohup.exe" "C:\Program Files\git\usr\bin\nohup.exe"
- mklink "C:\Program Files\Git\**cmd**\msys-2.0.dll" "C:\Program Files\git\usr\bin\msys-2.0.dll"
- mklink "C:\Program Files\Git\**cmd**\msys-iconv-2.dll" "C:\Program Files\git\usr\bin\msys-iconv-2.dll"
- mklink "C:\Program Files\Git\**cmd**\msys-intl-8.dll" "C:\Program Files\git\usr\bin\msys-intl-8.dll"

Comment: @John...The above solution not working for me, I have git-bash installed and set the path variable. Also link made on bin and cmd, still I have error

Comment: Worked great for me

Comment: I installed cygwin but still get the same error

Answer (score 22):

With Git for Windows 2.16.2, I was able to add C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin to the PATH (rather than C:\Program Files\Git\bin) and consequently my sh commands work in both FreeStyle and Pipeline builds. No mklink was necessary. ([Source](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33708?focusedCommentId=333102&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-333102))

Comment: adding C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin to user Path and restarting Jenkins worked for me

Comment: woorking for me too (after jenkins restart).  should be the accepted answer

Comment: Just beware which PATH variable you edit. I was running Jenkins as me, then I switched to system & this broke again. This was because I had added "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin" to the **USER** PATH initially, but when I switched to run Jenkins as system, I needed to add "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin" to the **SYSTEM** PATH.

Comment: This was the most accurate and effective answer, IMHO.

Answer (score 18):

If you are executing on Windows, just change sh to bat. it will work as expected.
Example:

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('Compile Stage') {

```
        steps {
            withMaven(maven : 'apache-maven-3.6.1') {
                bat'mvn clean compile'
            }
        }
    }
```

}
}

Comment: Thanks for this answer it saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 13):

With Git for Windows, I had to add `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` to the `PATH` environment variable of the slave node in Jenkins (to get access to `sh`), then add `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` to the `PATH` locally on the Windows slave too (to get access to `nohup`).

Answer (score 7):

Windows doesn't understand the "sh" command. To enable this, add

C:\Program Files\Git\bin &

C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin

to the System Environment variable PATH, than restart your system.

Than execute your command in jenkins, it will work.

Answer (score 6):

Switching sh to bat worked for me - I am running Jenkins on Windows. But only after I had resolved an issue caused by the fact I had not configured my tools (maven and the JDK) correctly in Jenkins either.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I replaced 'sh' by 'bat' in Pipeline script and worked.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error below solutions worked for me..

1. Install git-bash
2. for windows use "bat" instead of "sh"
3. set "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin" to PATH(user variable)

Answer (score 2):

sh is not windows command. The simple way to enable the use of 'sh' command in windows is to install [GIT BASH](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

Once you install GIT BASH, then you need to set below environment variables path.

1. C:\Program Files\Git\bin : This path contains sh.exe, bash.exe and git.exe
2. C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin : This path contains several Linux based exe and dll (cat.exe, find.exe etc.)

By setting above configuration you will be able to execute 'sh' command in Jenkinsfiles on Jenkins installed on windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

My observation is that the agent seems to be trying to run nohup in the context where the agent.jar is run, not in the container.  It didn't matter what I put in the container, the error message was the same.  By putting nohup and sh in the PATH where the jenkins agent is running, I see a change in behavior.

> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
>   git checkout -f c64c7bf905b6a4f5a8f85eb23bbd108f4c805386
>   sh: /home/jenkins/workspace/projname/simple_docker@tmp/durable-9fedc317/jenkins-log.txt: No such file or directory
>   sh: /home/jenkins/workspace/projname/simple_docker@tmp/durable-9fedc317/jenkins-result.txt.tmp: No such file or directory
>   mv: cannot stat '/home/jenkins/workspace/projname/simple_docker@tmp/durable-9fedc317/jenkins-result.txt.tmp': No such file or directory

I am seeing a folder /home/jenkins/workspace/projname/simple_docker@tmp/durable-9fedc317 which contains a file "script.sh" with the contents "docker inspect -f . repositoryname:tagname"

When this docker command is run manually on the command line, it always produces a single line of output consisting of a single period character.  I have no doubt this is not what the jenkins system is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the job running under WSL.  If you want all jobs running under WSL have you considered installing Jenkins under WSL? Then everything is already in GNU land and you don't have to bridge the envrionment/culture of windows to GNU from within your Jenkins configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I got the above issue in windows 10 and just added the path **"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin"** to the system variables then it started working.