# Batch as a windows service

Tags: windows, jenkins, process, command-prompt

I am running a Jenkins on windows machine with the process of Jenkins.war.
'java -jar jenkins.war'. If I close the command prompt of the service, Jenkins will go down. I want the Jenkins to be up even if the command prompt closed and even after machine reboot, this jenkins to be started. How can we do this on windows machine?

Comment: Possibly by making nohup available for Jenkins as detailed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140614/jenkins-pipeline-sh-fail-with-cannot-run-program-nohup-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [create-windows-service-from-executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable) to make your jenkins.exe as a service. Or else while installing itself, install as a service rather than starting from `command line`