# Jenkins pipeline: Run python script

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to run a python file or set of python commands via a JenkinsFile. How do I approach this?

I run the code below and My Jenkins Job never finishes.

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'python:3.5.1' } }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'python --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you are using one of the hello world examples of Jenkins (https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/) your code should work. Is your Jenkinsfile placed in your repository? Or can you provide more jenkins output?

Comment: Yes, I am using same jenkins example as mentioned in Windows machine..

Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "nohup" (in directory "D:\OCIPlatformIDC\jenkins\workspace\githubpipeline"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Where is your docker host, on same Windows machine as of Jenkins? and have you configured it in the Jenkins global configuration.

Comment: What is the console log for the job?

Answer (score 1):

I got your pipeline working by following the below steps:

1. Create a `Pipeline` job with the code you posted in the question.

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'python:3.5.1' } }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'python --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

2. Install docker on the virtual machine console and add the jenkins user to docker group

```
sudo apt install docker.io
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl start docker
docker --version
> Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins
```

3. Run the job, you must get a `success` and `python version` like in below screenshot.

[image]

Feel free to ask any questions, if required.

Comment: Jenkins installed in Windows, Docker as well. So do I have to add the Jenkin user to docker group?

I am getting below mentioned error for jenkins build:
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "nohup" (in directory "D:\OCIPlatformIDC\jenkins\workspace\githubpipeline"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Please have a look here.`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140614/jenkins-pipeline-sh-fail-with-cannot-run-program-nohup-on-windows`