# Getting java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

While running the jenkins pipeline code below i am getting below error. I am getting error unable to find the file in the specified location. so i tryed many ways but getting same error.

Even if anyone know how to write jenkins file also can comment it or if you have any url for that also can you post in the comment. This will help a lot

```
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:487)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:154)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
        at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
        at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
        at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:996)
        at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:508)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.launchWithCookie(BourneShellScript.java:236)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launch(FileMonitoringTask.java:103)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.start(DurableTaskStep.java:320)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:319)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:193)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:158)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "nohup" (in directory "C:\Users\sambe\.jenkins\workspace\KaratePipeLine"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
        at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
        at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
        at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:996)
        at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:508)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.launchWithCookie(BourneShellScript.java:236)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launch(FileMonitoringTask.java:103)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.start(DurableTaskStep.java:320)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:319)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:193)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:158)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
        at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
        at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:14)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.delegateAndExecute(ModelInterpreter.groovy:137)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:661)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(ModelInterpreter.groovy:395)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(ModelInterpreter.groovy:393)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:660)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:288)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.toolsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:539)
        at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor195.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

This is the jenkins file code

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    tools{
        maven 'Maven'
    }
    stages{
        stage("SCM Checkout"){
            steps{
            git 'https://github.com/samben01/KarateWithJenkins.git'
            }
        }
        stage("Maven Build"){
            steps{
                sh 'mvn clean package'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have attached all the data above if anyone know the answer please answer the question

Comment: Take a look at [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140614/jenkins-pipeline-sh-fail-with-cannot-run-program-nohup-on-windows) and on this [JENKINS-33708](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-33708). Basically yo are trying to run an `sh` step on a Windows system which is not supported, use `bat` step instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
 In Linux/Mac we have to use 'sh' command.
```

```
In windows we have to use 'bat' command.
```

### Jenkins Code:

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    tools{
        maven 'Maven'
    }
    stages{
        stage("SCM Checkout"){
            steps{
            git 'https://github.com/samben01/KarateWithJenkins.git'
            }
        }
        stage("Maven Build"){
            steps{
                bat 'mvn clean package'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running the job which executes a Shell block on an Windows agent.
Instead of using the "agent any", try to see if you can run this against a Linux agent if you plan to use the Shell block or change the Shell block to a bat and run it against a Windows agent.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the error for JDK for Jenkins, where I found in .jenkins in config.xml  that the old JDK path was mentioned. I have changed as per `%PATH%`.

The issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, this issue is resolved by specifing the agent to Linux or update the `sh` commands. Another option, would be to specify the agent either with name or with a label running.

This would require you to specify the add a label to jenkins agent before.

```
pipeline{
agent { 
    label 'linux'
}
tools{
    maven 'Maven'
}
stages{
    stage("SCM Checkout"){
        steps{
        git 'https://github.com/....' #... should be your git path
        }
    }
    stage("Maven Build"){
        steps{
            sh 'mvn clean package'
        }
    }
}
```

}